# How to check if a particular ID does not exist then only enter into the logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that there are 1000 of pages and each page has a unique ID. I want to apply a JavaScript code on all these pages except for one page ID (example id = 43431).

This is the code I have written(below) but for some reason the JavaScript code is still getting applied to this particular page (#43431) as well, even though I have written it so that it does not apply to this particular page.

```js
// enter into the JS code if only this particular page ID does not exist.
if($('div').not('#43431')){
   // some JS code....
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class = "Test Home" id = "43431"> </div>
```

Am I missing something in my if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because your condition always returns `true`, for two reasons:

1. `$('div').not('#43431')` doesn't do what you think it does. Instead, it takes all divs and then narrows the collection to the ones that don't have ID equal to `43431`.
2. But that's not all. Even if previous problem didn't exist, the code still wouldn't work. Even empty jQuery collections evaluate to `true`:

```js
$('#lolWhatTheHeck') == true // true
```

What you're looking for is checking whether a particular element exists:

```js
if ($('#43431').length === 0) {
    // Element with ID=43431 doesn't exist
}
```